# Merging keys of two interfaces when passing to generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, index-signature

I have two interfaces as follows:

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
}

interface Bar {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}
```

My goal is to create a type that combines these two interface keys with underline between them, something like this:

```
type MergeKeys<A,B> = {
  [P in keyof A + '_' + P2 in keyof B]: string;
};

type Result = MergeKeys<Foo,Bar>;
```

So that the result would be:

```
   interface Result {
      foo_prop1: string;
      foo_prop2: string;
    }
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2ao1W) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
type MergeKeys<A, B> = { [P in
  `${Exclude<keyof A, symbol>}_${Exclude<keyof B, symbol>}`
  ]: string; };
```

The main idea is to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to perform the desired string concatenation.

The only wrinkle is that the compiler will reject the simpler `` `${keyof A}_${keyof B}` ``, because TypeScript [supports `symbol`-valued keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types) which cannot be serialized to strings via template literals.  In order to convince the compiler to serialize `keyof A`, we have to get rid of the possibility that any `symbol`-valued keys will be in there.  That's where [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) comes in.  The type `Exclude<keyof A, symbol>` will return [the union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the keys of `A` which are not `symbol`s (so you'll get any `string` or `number` [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) but no `symbol`s).

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
type Result = MergeKeys<Foo, Bar>;
/* type Result = {
    foo_prop1: string;
    foo_prop2: string;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyMmAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4EGiSyIoBCcUOBIgAco6IQEZyVGiAaDkIsQCYp1Oo3wt8rfGACeQlAFlotCAGkIeigB4AggBpk3AHzIAvDmQBtAArJQeQADABJsAFEADwQAGwBXABMIGwBrK3QYZEdKPQBbACN0GJcmAH0wqNjE5LS9DOcnCjzC4qYg+QBdVRkGZCYNAn1DZAAlCAo4mLAPZBMoM0trGwx0J14oFw0AegAqZCGUMYmpmbxCImJMUsUJbvV5IhJ0a9EhFUo1WQ0mZB2toA)